# Set sort order for UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

Is it possible to set a sort order for a `UIStackView`? For example, I want to sort it by time. Each subview has a `time` property which is just an `Int`.

I know you can sort a `UITableView` by sorting the array and then refreshing the table but `UIStackView` doesn't have delegates and data sources like that so I don't know how to go about this. It just seems to go by the order you add the subviews in which makes it challenging to add a view in the middle without removing everything first.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a table view for this.

Comment: Why should I do that?

Comment: Why? Because certain tools are made to perform certain tasks. It doesn't mean you can't use them... but you wouldn't use a hammer to screw in a screw.

Comment: You were right. I have since changed to a UITableView.

Comment: Glad I could be of some help :D Good work getting it working :D

Comment: Well I was thinking about how I was going to refresh the data in the view with a refresh control and I was feeling lazy so I refactored it to use a table view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe read [the documentation?](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview)

> The stack view manages the layout of all the views in its 
>   `arrangedSubviews`
>    property. These views are arranged along the stack view’s axis, based on their order in the 
>   `arrangedSubviews`
>    array.

Comment: So can a sort this array whenever I want without worrying about performance?

Comment: That is a get only property but reading the documentation did help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616232-arrangedsubviews has all the specific information you should need. If you're doing this so often that performance might be an issue, you should use UICollectionView or UITableView

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all arrangedSubviews and add or insert them again in you own order. Make sure this subviews is not hidden, because stackView sort them to head of arrangedSubviews array